# How to hide a column but still access its value?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview, with some columns. I want to hide one column, but still access its value when I select a record.

Could someone help me to achieve this?

Any Help is appreciated.

This is my gridview:  OutlookID is the column to hide!
 `<asp:GridView ID="gvOutlookMeldingen" runat="server" 
                AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                AutoGenerateSelectButton="True" onselectedindexchanged="GridView_SelectedIndexChanged">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Melder" HeaderText="Melder" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Onderwerp" HeaderText="Onderwerp" />
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Omschrijving">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <div style="overflow:auto; width: 500px; height: 150px;">
                                <asp:Label ID="lblOmschrijving" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Omschrijving")%>'></asp:Label>
                            </div>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Meldingsdatum" HeaderText="Meldingsdatum" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="OutlookID" HeaderText="OutlookID" Visible="false" />
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>`

This is the code when I select a record:

```
Label lblOmschrijving = (Label)gvOutlookMeldingen.SelectedRow.FindControl("lblOmschrijving");
            //Label lblOutlookID = (Label)gvOutlookMeldingen.SelectedRow.FindControl("lblOutlookID");

            Response.Redirect("Detailscherm.aspx?"
                + "melder=" + Server.UrlEncode(gvOutlookMeldingen.SelectedRow.Cells[1].Text)
                + "&meldingsdatum=" + gvOutlookMeldingen.SelectedRow.Cells[4].Text
                + "&onderwerp=" + Server.UrlEncode(gvOutlookMeldingen.SelectedRow.Cells[2].Text)
                + "&outlookid=" + Server.UrlEncode(gvOutlookMeldingen.SelectedRow.Cells[5].Text)
                + "&omschrijving=" + Server.UrlEncode(lblOmschrijving.Text)
                + "&niv1=" + ""
                + "&niv2=" + "");
```

Comment: You can use TemplateColumn and set css property of wanted item to display:none;

Comment: Access its value in client-side code or server-side code?  In what context?

Comment: @eugeneK this doesn't work because I can still see the column only the values disappear. and I can't get the value

Comment: @Tassisto, what do you mean by "get the value"? What are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to 
(1)hide the column in the gridview.
(2)when I select a record.
(3)I'll be redirected to another page.
(4)I must get the value of the hidden column
(5)and show it in a textbox in another page

Comment: Have you tried setting the width to "0" ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set this code after you've binded the data. To get this functionality I do this:

```
MyGridView.Columns[0].visible = true;
MyGridView.DataBind();
MyGridView.Columns[0].visible = false;
```

With this the first column is hidden, but you should be able to acces it's value.

Comment: It always has worked for me.  Maybe you should post your code so we can see exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: Ok, I would remove the Visible="false" tag from the OutlookID column and only use the code behind to make the column invisible once the gridview is databound.

Comment: That's it, I was setting the columns' visibility to false before binding the data.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the data to be available on the client side, you'll have to set the server-side `Visible = "False"` property of whatever [DataControlField](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datacontrolfield.aspx) you're using (preferably in the markup). You'll still be able to access the column from the server side.

You might want to consider using the GridView's [DataKeys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.datakeys.aspx) property - it might be more suited to your needs.

Comment: Are you sure the rows are populating correctly during the postback?  Set a breakpoint at the code you provided and watch `gvOutlookMeldingen.Rows` and `gvOutlookMeldingen.SelectedRow`.

If all you're doing is redirecting to the page and passing QueryString parameters, why not make the Select column a [HyperLinkField](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hyperlinkfield.aspx), with the DataNavigateUrlFields and DataNavigateUrlFormatString set to provide that data you need in the QueryString?

Answer (score 0):

Create Template column instead of your SELECT button. Set

> PostbackUrl='<%#
>   Eval("somepage.aspx?id={0}","wanted
>   column") %>'

. Remove column via designer.

Answer (score 0):

You can also set it invisible at the client side. With Javascript.

```
document.getElementById(myObject).visible = "false";
```

Answer (score 0):

when we set visiblity of control false in Design time that will be not render .Try to 
set visiblity =false in  gridView rowCreated Event .in below code  i am setting 
second column visibility= false

protected void grid_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                e.Row.Cells[2].Visible = false;

```
        }
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
        {
            e.Row.Cells[2].Visible = false;

        }
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer)
        {
            e.Row.Cells[2].Visible = false;

        }
    }
```

and now try to Get Value .Surely you will get the value.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.

You can't hide the column and keep value in code behind.

You have to hide it directly on client side with a javascript.

I did that :

On my css or page :

```
<style type="text/css">
.hiddencol
{
    display: none;
}
.viscol
{
    display: block;
}
</style>
```

Then add style into the BoundField of the gridViewer.

For example :

```
        <asp:BoundField DataField="AgentGUID" HeaderText="AgentGUID" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="AgentGUID"
            meta:resourcekey="BoundFieldResource1">
            <HeaderStyle CssClass="hiddencol" />
            <ItemStyle CssClass="hiddencol" />
            <FooterStyle CssClass="hiddencol" />
        </asp:BoundField>
```